# Minecraft Linux Don't Work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

After I pressed the "Play" button, Minecraft crashes after about 3 seconds. Here is the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mojang/patchy/LegacyXMLLayout : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.decodeCacheFiles(PluginRegistry.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.loadFromMainClassLoader(PluginRegistry.java:119)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.(PatternParser.java:132)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.(PatternParser.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createPatternParser(PatternLayout.java:246)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$SerializerBuilder.build(PatternLayout.java:375)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.(PatternLayout.java:128)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.(PatternLayout.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder.build(PatternLayout.java:652)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.setToDefault(AbstractConfiguration.java:577)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.(DefaultConfiguration.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.(LoggerContext.java:86)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:171)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:145)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:74)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:227)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:618)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper.configureLogging(LogWrapper.java:14)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper.log(LogWrapper.java:28)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:94)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means Minecraft is being run with a Java version that is too old to handle the files it is given. Class version 52 corresponds to Java 8, so you'll need 8 or newer to run Minecraft. If you already have that installed, please check that it is the default. If you need to keep Java 7 or earlier as the default, it should be possible to tell the launcher to use 8, but I think we'd need to know more about your setup to help with that. If you don't need the older version(s) at all, you should be safe to uninstall them.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but after I updated Java, I ran into another problem, can you help me with that? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327295/minecraft-linux-dont-work-cant-open-library