# Minecraft Linux Don't Work: Can't Open Library

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux

After I clicked "Play", Minecraft crashed in about 3 seconds, and here is the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/.minecraft/versions/1.12.2/1.12.2-natives-4081842886391/liblwjgl.so: /home/pi/.minecraft/versions/1.12.2/1.12.2-natives-4081842886391/liblwjgl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.(Sys.java:117)
    at bib.I(SourceFile:2825)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:38)
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: *Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform* .. wrong architecture...

Comment: Are you trying to run regular java minecraft on a raspi? You're probably not gonna get usable performance. How did you install it?

Comment: This might help: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221032/minecraft-on-arm-linux-samsung-chromebook?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you're trying to run the desktop version of Minecraft on an ARM device (probably a Raspberry Pi). You'll want to get a version better optimized for your platform. If you need help, please add that infromation to your question.